# airflow backfilling dag run dependancy

Tags: python, workflow, pipeline, airflow

When i backfill a dag for specific dates, i want to run it by sequentially, i.e. i want it to be run day by day

completing all the tasks for the specific day and then next day so on.. I have used the depends_on_past argument, but it is only helping me to set the dependency on tasks not in dag runs.

example :- Dag_A have 4 tasks , i use back fill with depends_on_past,
After executing first task in Dag_A (first day) it triggers first task of Dag_A (second day), I dont want it

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please show your own coding attempts. Maybe in the form of a [mcve], many users are very keen on seeing that. You might also want to take the [tour].

Comment: Perhaps in the dag max_active_runs= 1

Comment: I tried that too, It is not working in backfilling

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to set maximum number of runs per dag in the global airflow.cfg file. The parameter to set is max_active_runs_per_dag.

Comment: I had tried the same.. but it is not working in backfilling